# still need help-images inside wp-content/ uploads/ are not showing up in my media library and uploaded using FTP protocol

Tags: images, media-library

I'm having issues with being able to get to my image files inside the Media Library. I'm having issues, since I have transferred my WordPress website from my local server to the live environment.

In the below screenshot you can see the files are in the correct directory:

wp-content/uploads/

[image]

I did try to also just drag and drop an image into my media library but get this error-" could not insert post into the database".

I double checked my permissions and they are correct with folders set to 755 and files set to 644.

My wp-config.php file is also setup to the correct table for my .sql database

Also, I included this code:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '1024M');
```

to the wp-config.php file, so this isn't the issue.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you tried to regenerate your thumbnails? Plugins such as this will re-create the thumbnails from the image files in your media directory. https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/.

Depending how you transferred your wordpress site, the ID's may not match up etc anymore, try regenerate thumbnails on your live site.

Answer (score 0):

It looks, that there is a problem in your database, even more possible when you got "could not insert post into the database".

Have a look into your database, go to the wp_posts table and inspect entries with post_type "attachment". Here are the attachments saved in your database.

Pick several attachments and write down their ids. Then go to the wp_postmeta table and search the "post_id" with the id you wrote down. You should get additional information about the attachment, like the location of the file, etc. Are you getting those details correctly?

One more thing, make sure, that the database user has enough privileges granted for a selected database - this can be ofter set through cPanel or through some other hosting management dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where I could not add images to the Media Library. DanijelSVK prompted me to look at my database and this pointed me in the right direction (thank you).

It turns out my clients' database lost its Primary Keys and AUTO_INCREMENT for all tables. This happened during migration after a find/replace operation.

My fix involved 3 steps in phpMyAdmin:

1). Set Primary Keys for all tables (where missing).
2). Set AUTO_INCREMENT for all Primary Keys (where missing).
3). Manually delete all duplicate Primary Key entries.

That fixed it for me!

Details TL/DR....

My issue was a bit involved. I needed to migrate a new clients’ Wordpress site, but also had to update some of the URL's in the SQL file - which I did via Find/Replace on my desktop code editor (I have done this many times in the past).

After successfully importing the ‘updated’ SQL file into phpMyAdmin, both the website and Admin loaded fine, and 'seemed' fine, until I tried to add an image via the Media Library...I would get the same error as the OP - " could not insert post into the database".

On checking error logs, most were database errors stating: "WordPress database error: [Duplicate entry ‘0’ for key ‘PRIMARY’...]".

I then inspected the database via phpMyAdmin and noticed most tables showed the following error:

> "Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available"

I had to manually set the primary key for most tables. I 'thought' that would have fixed it, which it did NOT, as I got the same error (" could not insert post into the database") after trying to add an image into the Media Library.

On checking error logs (again) the original error remained (Duplicate entry ‘0’ for key ‘PRIMARY’). I then found several entries in various tables with duplicate keys with zero '0' being the duplicate. I deleted these duplictes and subsequent errors indicted that my Primary Keys were not set to AUTO_INCREMENT. Setting the primary keys to AUTO_INCREMENT finally fixed the issue.

Hope this helps someone.